# MySql how do I update table based on group by within that table?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

When I run the below query I get

> error #1093 - You can't specify target table 'x2' for update in FROM clause

```
update contacts 
set duplicates = 1
where email in ( select email from contacts 
    group by email
    having count(*) > 1)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do a JOIN to find other rows with the same email and a different primary key.

For example, assuming your primary key is called `id`:

```
UPDATE contacts AS c1
JOIN contacts AS c2 ON (c1.email = c2.email AND c1.id <> c2.id)
SET c1.duplicates = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can trick it by nesting the subquery.

```
update contacts set duplicates = 1 where email in 
(select email 
  from  
    (select email from contacts group by email having count(*) > 1) as a)
```